# I can't get an algorithm based on reading a character array to work

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I need to turn the inputted character array into all lowercases. The reading stops at the '.' character. I have to do it this way, without using the string variable nor any function inside the  library.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char s[200], *p=s;
    cin.getline(s, 200, '.');
    while(p){
        if('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z') *p += 'A'-'a';
        p++;
    }
    cout << s;
}
```

The algorithm is supposed to check every character in the array until it meets a null pointer. For every character, it should then check if it is a lowercase character. If it is, it changes it into an uppercase letter (by decreasing 'a' it memorises the difference between the first letter of the alphabet and the letter it is referring to, by increasing 'A' it adds that difference to the first letter of the uppercase alphabet, so to speak, thus obtaining the uppercase version of the letter).

I've no clue where my mistake is, but my compiler crashes when I try to run it.

Comment: You may want to put the `cin` on the same line as `while`; or use better coding style (such as substatements on separate lines, spacing between operators, etc.).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks for noticing. It actually used to be that way, but I eliminated the spacings to go through my code to see if there's any mistake. I should have placed it all back the way it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (p)
```

should be

```
while (*p)
```

If you're looking to stop on the null terminator, you need to dereference the pointer or you'll test that the pointer isn't null instead.

Sidenote: You may find the `std::tolower` function helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realise that. Also, I'll check out that function

Comment: I just now realised what that function does. You see, I'm solving exercises from a book. The book itself has shown me a function in the <string> library I could have used, but the exercise explicitly mentioned not to (to test my abilities). I'll keep that function in mind, though!